# DAX calculating running sum of column

Tags: dax, cumulative-sum

I have already tried the various solutions found on the web (which are usually all the same), but nothing works.
As suggested in https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Issue-with-Running-Total/td-p/310720
I tried using the dates column as a reference
[image]

Then I created an index column in Power Query and use this as a reference
[image]

As you can see it simply doesn't work:
instead of getting a running sum, starting from the first value (€ 37 800.68), I simply get a global  sum.

I have also tried creating a *Quick New Measure* selecting the *Running Total* option (see the full function automatically generated by Power BI) and then displaying the result with a chart in the report window, but again the result doesn't make sense (I simply get a copy of the field I want to sum...)
[image]

**UPDATE**

I implemented the suggestion by @sigdoug but I get the following
[image]

This is simply adding to each element in the column *Amount* the following value, forgetting the previous one.

What I mean by *running sum* is update the sum of the previous calculation.

I should get the following values:
37 800.68
35,845.11
35,348.57‬
35,347.57
...‬
‬

Can someone help me in getting this right? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry andrea, I should have actually done a bigger test of this (and read the question properly). The following will solve your problem, add this as a calculated column:

```
SUMX(FILTER('Table','Table'[Column1<=EARLIER
('Table'[Column1])),'Table'[Column2])
```

column1 being your index and column2 being the value you want added each time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however a few it doesn't work: your point 2) is already in place; point 3) does not produce a running total. Perhaps you meant that the +'Table'[Column2] should go in the LOOKUPVALUE function, but even in that case, it does not produce a running total

Comment: No the lookupvalue function will not accept the addition, it must be outside of this function. However, it should be within the "if" formula, this will get the previous value from the prior indexed value (I have edited the answer to reflect). Check your index column in your dataset, to make sure you have it in the correct order. I've just run a dummy dataset to show you this working, let me know if you'd like me to send you a link.

Comment: It looks like we have a different definition of _running sum_ . I edited the post ì, to make sure everybody understands what I mean

Comment: Sorry andrea! My fault, you're absolutely right. Answer updated.